# Get All Table Rows, Not Default Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to scrape all the table data off the following site: 
https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s

The table has a total of 230 rows (not including header row), but defaults to the first 50 rows. When I click the next page button (arrow) on the table, a new set or rows loads, but the webpage does not change. How can I use BeautifulSoup to get all 230 rows instead of just the default 50?

This is the code I am using:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class':'stripe'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells[1:])

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "w", newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Last", "First", "Middle", "Gender", "Race", "Age", "City", "State"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `max_rows` parameter in the URL:

https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s?max_rows=500

Comment: Thank you, @jinksPadlock! That worked perfectly. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: If there was no way to set a max number of rows to view in the table, would there be any way to pull the results for the first page, then the second page, then the third, etc.?

Comment: Since the table reloads from setting the input value, your script would require handling javascript. Something like Selenium could do that.

Comment: Thanks, @jinksPadlock. I figured that situation will probably arise in the near future so wanted to know how to address it when it does. I really appreciate all your help.